# Эффект плавно меняющихся картинок при скролле

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу реализовать подобный эффект с картинками, как здесь http://ww1.lenta.ru/saraevo/ в Unity. Чтобы картинки двигались вверх-вниз, исчезали или появлялись при прокрутки колесика мышки или при движении пальцем по тачпаду.

Есть идея реализовать все это с помощью подобного скрипта:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI; 
public class img : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Image;
    void Update()
    {
        if(Image.transform.position.y < (0 - Image.size/2) 
           || Image.transform.position.y > (Screen.height + Image.size/2))
            Image.SetActive(false);
        else
            Image.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? Что конкретно не работает в коде?

Comment: Не могу найти чем заменить параметр .size в Image вот отсюда  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такой вариант будет приводить к щелчкам картинок, они не будут плавно растворяться как в примере.

Чтобы растворялось придется делать отрисовку через шейдеры с использованием Transparent, и в скрипте реализовывать анимацию Alpha у материала в момент перехода из видимой области в невидимую. Я бы сделал зону которая будет ограничивать область где видимость 100%. При входе центра объекта в зону исчезновения в зависимости от удаления от центра экрана подменял бы прозрачность в материале, и тогда бы получился эффект что чем дальше объект от зоны видимости тем больше исчезает. Если постараться можно и через градиент сделать растворение. Однако следует учитывать что использование transparent в материалах приведет к тому что тени без особых приседаний работать попросту не будут.

Вот в таком варианте у меня получилось. Скрипт накидал быстро, поэтому никакой оптимизации. Вешаем на каждую панель которая у нас будет содержать информацию в объекте Content для ScrollRect. Когда объект будет удаляться от центра Canvas( меня он был посередине экрана) то постепенно меняется цвет для каждого маскируемого объекта по альфе.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EffectScroll : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Image panel = null;
    private RectTransform root = null;
    private bool isOk = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        if (panel == null)
            panel = GetComponent<Image>();

        isOk = panel != null;
        if (isOk)
            root = panel.rectTransform.root as RectTransform;
        isOk = isOk && (root != null);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!isOk) return;

        Color color = panel.color;
        Vector2 center = GetCenter(root);
        Vector2 center2 = GetCenter(panel.rectTransform);
        float h2 = root.sizeDelta.y/2;
        float newAlpha = 1 - Mathf.Clamp(center2.y > center.y? center2.y - center.y: center.y - center2.y ,0.0F, h2)/h2;
        if (Mathf.Abs(color.a - newAlpha) > float.Epsilon)
        {
            color.a = newAlpha;
            panel.color = color;
            MaskableGraphic[] childs = GetComponentsInChildren<MaskableGraphic>();
            foreach (MaskableGraphic child in childs)
            {
                Color newColor = child.color;
                newColor.a = newAlpha;
                child.color = newColor;
            }
        }

    }

    private Vector2 GetCenter(RectTransform transform)
    {
        Vector2 center = transform.TransformPoint(transform.rect.center);//new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        return center;
    }
}
```

Другой вариант можно сделать постобработку на камере и если плашки отрисовываются в одной камере то брать целиком изображение и делать его исчезновение к краям.

Чтобы установить позицию скролируемой области в нужное место можно воспользоваться вот таким скриптом (вешаем его на объект со `ScrollRect`)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScrollStart : MonoBehaviour {

public enum AllignHorizontal
{
    None,
    Left,
    Center,
    Right
}
public enum AllignVertical
{
    None,
    Top,
    Center,
    Bottom
}

public ScrollRect main = null;
public AllignHorizontal Horizontal = AllignHorizontal.None;
public AllignVertical Vertical = AllignVertical.None;
public Text info;
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    if (main == null) main = GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
    if (main != null)
    {
        if (main.horizontal)
        {
            switch (Horizontal)
            {
                case AllignHorizontal.Left:
                    main.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0f;
                    break;
                case AllignHorizontal.Center:
                    main.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0.5f;
                    break;
                case AllignHorizontal.Right:
                    main.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 1f;
                    break;

            }

        }
        if (main.vertical)
        {
            switch (Vertical)
            {
                case AllignVertical.Top:
                    main.verticalNormalizedPosition = 1f;
                    break;
                case AllignVertical.Center:
                    main.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.5f;
                    break;
                case AllignVertical.Bottom:
                    main.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0f;
                    break;

            }

        }
        main.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChange);
    }
}

private void OnValueChange(Vector2 arg0)
{
    if (info != null)
    {
        info.text = arg0.ToString();
    }
}

}
```

Если есть необходимость синхронизовать два скрола, то следует на скролах  слушать событие `onValueChanged` и править соответсвенно у себя `verticalNormalizedPosition` и `horizontalNormalizedPosition` в соответствии с изменениями у соседа.

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример кода

Comment: Вот что у меня получилось https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxbRz7vfOBdrUlJzOHBlZ05GM3c/view?usp=sharing  Только картинки снизу не успевают плавно исчезать и появляться, когда находятся в поле зрения

Comment: Объекты в  scroll имели привязку пивота к левому верхнему углу, подправил код метода `GetCenter` теперь все должно быть нормально.

Comment: Возможно ли еще также реализовать sroll заднего фона. Т.е. если создать две Panel. Первая Panel будет Foreground, т.е. непосредственно сами страницы книги с анимацией, картинками и текстом. А вторая Panel будет содержать набор картинок Background. Когда, например, появляется страница с другим сюжетом, например на 4-ой странице, то Background должен скролиться вместе с 3-ей страницей и оставаться на месте еще несколько страниц.

Comment: Ну теоретически конечно все это можно реализовать. Придется делать второй скролл и между ними некую синхронизацию. Но времени на подобные развлечения извините нет

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, а не подскажите - в каком направлении можно "покопать", для синхронизации скролла?

Comment: Покопайте в сторону события `OnValueChanged`. Пример управления положением скрола добавил в основной ответ.

Comment: т.е. к скроллу в Foreground добавить скрипт Scroll Bar и в скролле Background отслеживать положение Scroll Bar из Foreground с помощью события OnValueChanged?

Comment: нет `ScrollBa`r не нужен, достаточно будет 'ScrollRect'. Если размеры объектов `Foreground` и `Background` совпадают, то вообще можно не заморачиваться и просто выставлять координаты объектов друг относительно друга по `OnValueChanged` не применяя второй скролируемой области

Comment: Переменной onValueChanged нет в SrollRect. Размеры Foreground и Background отличаются. Еще возникла такая идея - сделать анимацию для каждой картинки из Background. И по событию onValueChanged запускать анимацию движение изображения Background вверх или вниз. Вот только пока не слишком хорошо понимаю Event-driven Programming в Unity, читаю Mastering Unity Scripting от Alan Thron

Comment: Какой версией Unity пользуетесь? я в 5.0.1 все делаю. Добавил в пример как цепляться к событию. В `Start` добавил слушателя к событию `main.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChange);` и написал метод для обработки `OnValueChange`. В результате у меня выводится в текстовое поле координаты скролл вектора

Comment: Спасибо! У меня версия Unity 5.0.0f1. Я просто не нашел  **OnValueChange** в документации Unity к **SrollRect**. Теперь сравнивая значение **arg0.ToString()** можно менять положение Background **ScrollRect**.

Comment: Только не совсем до конца понимаю смысла в строчке кода **main.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChange)**

Comment: `main.onValueChanged` это объект, `AddListener` добавляет к нему слушателя, то бишь метод который будет запускаться при наступлении события. Паттерн наблюдатель, почитайте. Примерно то же что и делегаты, только на уровне объекта, позволяет немножко гибче быть, в плане что можно какие то доп параметры передавать и т.п.

Comment: С помощью проверки положения foregound скролла через **if (arg0.ToString()== "(0.0, 1.0)")**, меняюположение background скролла  **backGround.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.5f**.

Comment: столкнулся с проблемой, что метод **arg0.ToString()** округляет значения положения скролла до десятых. Т.е. невозможно выполнить сравнение, например, **arg0.ToString()== "(0.0, 0.82)"**, а можно сравнить лишь так **arg0.ToString()== "(0.0, 0,8)"** или так **arg0.ToString()== "(0.0, 0,9)"**

Comment: `arg0` это `Vector2`, поэтому вам гораздо удобнее будет использовать его свойства `x` и `y`, чем сравнивать строковое представление вектора (через `ToString()`). В свойствах как раз никакого округления не будет. Сравнивайте так: `(arg0.y >0.8f && arg0.y <0.9f)` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Благодарю, за маленький кусочек кода счастья)))

Comment: @Sevastopol' - пример был рабочий на момент написания) Сам проект уже не восстановить, поскольку с юнити почти не работаю последнее время.